# What does one '&' means in C and how i can use it?

Tags: c, operators

For example,here:

printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");

Comment: I may have initially learned C ages ago, but my book did contain a chapter on this topic, that much I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's means "bits checking" by & bitwise operation with S_IRUSR macros,sry guys for this stupid question.